# How to convert piece of JSP to the Thymeleaf syntax?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

I have some JSP, what I want convert to the Thymeleaf:

```
<c:forEach var="portfolioWork" items="${portfolioWorks}" varStatus="statusVariable">

    <c:set var="stylesStr" value="" />
    <c:if test="${not empty portfolioWork.getPublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations()}">
        <c:forEach  var="wRels" items="${portfolioWork.getPublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations()}">
            <c:set var="stylesStr" value="${stylesStr} type${wRels.getPublicSitePortfolioWorkTypes().getId()} " />
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>

<div class="element ${stylesStr} block">
*****************************************
```

I can't understand, how to convert this complex structure:

```
<c:set var="stylesStr" value="" />
<c:if test="${not empty portfolioWork.getPublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations()}">
    <c:forEach  var="wRels" items="${portfolioWork.getPublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations()}">
        <c:set var="stylesStr" value="${stylesStr} type${wRels.getPublicSitePortfolioWorkTypes().getId()} " />
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the best way to implement this is to create a custom AttrProcessor that sets a class attribute value, based on "portfolioWorks" variable. So it will look like:

```
<div class="element block" some_scope:appendClass="${portfolioWorks}"></div>
```

Take a look at: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/extendingthymeleaf.html#attribute-processors

I would also recommend looking through thymeleaf sources, there are plenty of different attr processors, so you will be able to get the idea more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *th:with* attribute for setting variable, but unfortunately it is visible only within block where it was defined. (http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables) Thus, you need to modify a bit your logic.

```
<c:if test="${not empty portfolioWork.getPublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations()}">
   <c:forEach  var="wRels" items="${portfolioWork.getPublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations()}">
      <div class="element ${wRels.getPublicSitePortfolioWorkTypes().getId()} block">
   </c:forEach>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty portfolioWork.getPublicSitePortfolioWorksToTypeRelations()}">
   <div class="element block">
</c:if>
```

With such logic *c:if* can be easily updated to *th:block* with *th:if* or *th:unless* and then you process your div block there inside.

If that looks bit ugly - you could define your  block in some other html file as a fragment (th:fragment) and call it using th:include and passing the parameter *${wRels.getPublicSitePortfolioWorkTypes().getId()}* inside. You can read more about templates here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout

If you need more info or details, please tell me :)